# why getting Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the [.tsv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uJaa8YgInoCQm4mRUNTMayefAkhmI9xZ/view?usp=sharing) for the following script.

Source code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


adder_dd_with_yyyy_mm <- function(date) {
  if(str_count(date, "-") == 1) {
    return(paste(date, "01", sep = "-"))
  } else {
    return(date)
  }
}

date_abbreviator <- function(date) {
  month <- strftime(date, format = "%b")
  year <- strftime(date, format = "%y")
  return(paste(month, year, sep = "-"))
}


df <- read.csv("figure_metadata.tsv", sep = "\t")

df$date <- df$date %>% lapply(adder_dd_with_yyyy_mm) %>%
  lapply(date_abbreviator)


ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = date, fill = clade))
```

It's sure that no missing value in `date` and `clade` columns.
I'm getting the error `Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`. Can anyone help, please? Thanks.

Comment: @r2evans how can I convert `list` to `data.frame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of your `df$date` reassignment is a `list`, not a vector. This can be fixed in a number of ways:

```r
df$date <- df$date %>%
  lapply(adder_dd_with_yyyy_mm) %>%
  sapply(date_abbreviator)
## or
df$date <- df$date %>%
  lapply(adder_dd_with_yyyy_mm) %>%
  lapply(date_abbreviator) %>%
  unlist(.)
```

Both of those techniques run a slight risk (without looking more in-depth at your processing) that if any function returns an object of length other than 1, reassignment may fail. However, if all of that goes well, then

```r
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = date, fill = clade))
```

[image]

I suggest that since your x-axis is a categorical, the labels will always be bunched up. It might be better to treat them as a *real `Date`-class object*.

---

This process is a bit slow, mostly because you are operating on one `$date` at a time; R is good at doing things whole vectors at a time, so your labeling might do better with something like:

```r
func1 <- function(x) {
  paste0(x, ifelse(str_count(x, "-") == 1, "-01", ""))
}
func1(head(df$date))
# [1] "2020-04-09" "2020-04-08" "2020-04-20" "2020-06-18" "2020-06-18" "2020-03-13"
```

to do all of the first function in one step. The second step can equally be vectorized,

```r
func2 <- function(x) {
  format(as.Date(x), format = "%b-%y")
}
func2(func1(head(df$date)))
# [1] "Apr-20" "Apr-20" "Apr-20" "Jun-20" "Jun-20" "Mar-20"
```

These could likely be combined into a single function:

```r
func <- function(x) {
  format(as.Date(paste0(x, ifelse(str_count(x, "-") == 1, "-01", ""))), 
         format = "%b-%y")
}
func(head(df$date))
# [1] "Apr-20" "Apr-20" "Apr-20" "Jun-20" "Jun-20" "Mar-20"
```

---

Ultimately, though, I generally prefer and recommend keeping date-like objects as `Date`-class objects and having `ggplot2` do some formatting.

```r
# df <- read.csv(...)
df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$date, ifelse(nchar(df$date) < 10, "-01", "")))

head(df$date)
# [1] "2020-04-09" "2020-04-08" "2020-04-20" "2020-06-18" "2020-06-18" "2020-03-13"
lubridate::floor_date(head(df$date), unit="months")
# [1] "2020-04-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-03-01"

df$date <- as.Date(lubridate::floor_date(df$date, unit="months"))
head(df$date)
# [1] "2020-04-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-03-01"
class(df$date)
# [1] "Date"

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = date, fill = clade)) +
  scale_x_date(labels = function(z) format(z, format = "%b-%y"))
```

[image: ggplot2, with date-class x-axis]

If you need all of the axis ticks, then (as above) it will get busy. We can control which are shown using `breaks=`, and then optionally rotate the labels.

```r
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = date, fill = clade)) +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = function(z) seq(lubridate::floor_date(z[1], "month"), lubridate::ceiling_date(z[2], "month"), by = "month"),
    labels = function(z) format(z, format = "%b-%y")
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image: ggplot with all x-axis ticks/labels, rotated]

*Edited to fix a `breaks=` bug. Note that `Jan-20` and `Aug-21` are included mostly because most plot functions expand the axes a little when working with numerical data.

Comment: there is no sample in Jan-20. But why the graph is showing?

Comment: there are samples for July-21 but no bar in the graph.

Comment: "Jan-20": because `ggplot2` expands numeric axes by default. "July-21": bug in my `breaks=` code, fixing in a moment .... see my edit.